# How can I change this javascript so the contents of it get submitted to my rails form?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In rails, I have a form with the id: 'new_user', which when submitted creates a new user. I'm trying to make sure that the following javascript works:

```
    var form$ = $("#new_user");
                var token = response['id'];
                form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='Token' value='" + token + "' />");
                form$.get(0).submit();
```

What I want it to do is add the 'Token' to my Rails form when I submit the form. How can I go about changing the javascript so the 'Token' gets submitted to the form with an id 'new_user'? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `token` in the `params` hash as part of `user`, try giving the input an appropriate id and name:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user[token]" id="user_token" .../>
```

Then you should be able to access it in your controller as `params[:user][:token]`